# Помогите понять ошибку в коде

Tags: python

В учебных целях требуется обойтись базовыми средствами языка, без импортирования специализированных модулей

**Описание**

Предположим, имеется N станций, занумерованных целыми числами от 0 до N (не включительно), и таблица цен билетов на проезд от каждой станции до каждой. Стоимость проезда из любой станции на саму себя равна, конечно, нулю, и к тому же стоимость проезда A→B равна стоимости проезда B→A . В таком случае получается, что если мы хотим ввести такую таблицу цен (и дальше что-то ещё делать с ней в программе), то достаточно ввести её лишь без малого наполовину.

Напишите программу, которая по половине таблицы цен достраивает полную таблицу и записывает ее в переменную table, а затем выводит.

**Формат ввода**

На первой строке вводится число N — количество станций и размер итоговой таблицы.
Далее следует N-1 строка чисел, эти строки составляют нижнюю левую часть таблицы: на первом ряду дана цена билета между станциями 0 и 1, на втором — и , и так далее.

**Формат вывода**

Выводится полная таблица цен на билеты, достроенная по входным данным, как в примере.

**Пример**

**Ввод**

```
5
3
6 1
6 6 1
8 3 2 5
```

**Вывод:**

```
0 3 6 6 8
3 0 1 6 3
6 1 0 1 2
6 6 1 0 5
8 3 2 5 0
```

Не до конца понимаю, почему, но мой код работает с какой то ошибкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тогда у меня неправильно, я просто хочу узнать, может есть какой-нибудь способ исправить это?

Вот такой код у меня получился:

```
n, table = int(input()), [['0']]
for i in range(n - 1): 
    table.append((input() + ' 0').split())
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(i):
        table[j].append(table[i][j])
for row in table:
    print(*row)
```

Comment: Ваша таблица не содержит чисел. А именно это требуется

Comment: согласен, я уже попробовал так и ничего не получилось все равно: `for row in [[int(i) for i in elem] for elem in table]:     print(*row)`

Comment: Они проверяют переменную table , а не результат печати

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ошибке написано: вам нужно создать список с **числами**, а у вас список **строк**.

```
n = int(input())
table = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]

        
for i in range(1, n):
    temp = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        table[i][j] = temp[j]
        table[j][i] = temp[j]


for row in table:
    print(*row)
```

Comment: согласен, я уже попробовал так и ничего не получилось все равно: `for row in [[int(i) for i in elem] for elem in table]:
    print(*row)`

Comment: @марат у вас должен быть массив чисел

Comment: а не подскажите пожалуйста тогда как это реализовать?

Comment: @марат, добавил